# Searching dictionary for matching key from a textbox C#

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, wpf-controls

I'm reading a csv file that contains abbreviations and the full version for example LOL,Laughing out Loud. I've created a dictionary where the abbreviation is the key and full version is the value.

'''

```
    private void btnFilter_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        var keys = new List<string>();
        var values = new List<string>();
        using (var rd = new StreamReader("textwords.csv"))
        {
            while (!rd.EndOfStream)
            {
                var splits = rd.ReadLine().Split(',');
                keys.Add(splits[0]);
                values.Add(splits[1]);
            }
        }
        var dictionary = keys.Zip(values, (k, v) => new { Key = k, Value = v }).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);


        foreach (var k in dictionary)
        {
            //
        }

        aMessage.MessageContent = txtContent.Text;
    }
```

'''

I'm using a button that will check if the textbox txtContent contains any of the abbreviations in the text and change this to the full version. So if the textbox contained the following. "Going to be AFK" after the button click it would change this to "Going to be away from keyboard".

I want to write a foreach loop that would check for any abbreviations, elongate them and then save this to a string variable MessageContent.

Would anyone be able to show me the best way to go about this as I'm not sure how to do this with the input from a textbox?

Thanks

Comment: Any reason why you don't use the proper Dictionary class? Retrieving a key/value in a dictionary is really simple

Comment: I'm fairly new to WPF so I wasn't sure how to read the .CSV straight in to the dictionary and instead just opted to convert two lists instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use LINQ to read and create a dictionary object:

```
 var dictionary = File.ReadAllLines(@"textwords.csv")
                  .Select(x => x.Split(",",StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                   .ToDictionary(key => key.FirstOrDefault().Trim(), 
                    value =>  value.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault().Trim());
```

Comment: Ah thank you, this is a much better way I'll quickly rectify this.

Answer (score -1):

If the abbrevs are correct, i.e. you don't need fuzzy logic, you can use a variety of .NET objects and search the keys rather quickly.

```
if(dict.ContainsKey(myKey))
{
}
```

I did that freehand, so it might be dict.Keys.Contains() or similar. The point is you can search the dictionary directly rather than loop.

If you need to do a more fuzzy search, you can utilize LINQ to write queries to iterate over collections of objects extremely fast (and few lines).

As for yours, you would iterate over dictionary.Keys to seach keys, but I still don't see why you need the extra code.